# Logging high-level game events to external consumer

Tags: architecture

Is there any existing technology/framework/standard for publishing high-level game events to a consumer?

Example:

Imagine a game which can publish events like change of level, player joined, player left, final score.

Then theoretically it's possible to have a plugin for e.g. OBS that inserts metadata info into the video it's recording. So you might have, say, video chapters automatically defined for different levels being played.

I had a look and couldn't see much, but maybe I'm not searching for the right term.

Comment: Depends entirely on the publishing mechanism you have in mind. If it's a plaintext log file, there are lots of logging frameworks out there. If it's on a socket/port/endpoint, the question becomes "which protocol?". There are *lots* of messaging and notification protocols out there too.

Comment: Right, there probably is no standard for what you specifically want to do; But there are lots of tools and standards out there that you can utilize for what you want to do. You haven't really defined a concrete problem to solve so it's hard to give a proper stack exchange answer too.

Comment: Some things to consider and edit into your question: Is this publish mechanism event-driven? Or does the client poll? Do you have an OBS module that can pull data in mind? If so, how does it work? Do you only want to publish to the local machine? Or the local network/internet? Is entering a target hostname/IP acceptable? Or do you need zero-configuration? Do you only ever need to send a simple text string? Or might you also want image data like a profile pic/level thumbnail?

Comment: Thanks for great comments all, editing the question shortly